# @Before and @After exclusion

Tags: java, hibernate, session, junit

I'm writing some tests for my DAO, and because a lot of the tests use a test object that is being saved to my database I've created a setup() and teardown() method with the annotations @Before and @After respectively to avoid redundant code, but one of the tests, actually one that doesn't really need the test object, calls a method in the DAO that contains the call getCurrentSession().clear() (it's a method that uses ScrollableResults to get data from the db in batches, and to avoid the memory to fill up it calls flush() and clear() every 50 rows). This creates a problem, because the clear() actually removes the test object that is created in setup() from the session, so when teardown() is called I get an error:

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [nl.ru.cmbi.pdbeter.core.model.domain.PDBEntry#395]
```

Is there a way to tell JUnit to not use the setup() and teardown() on this test, or is it better to put all the tests that don't actually need the setup() and teardown() in a new test class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all yes, it makes a lot of sense to isolate tests that don't need the `@Before` or `@After` behavior in a separate test.

Secondly, you may want to take a look at the [Spring Framework's support for running unit tests within a database transaction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testing-tx) that is automatically rolled back at the end of each test, so that you do not have to ever worry about some tests affecting the state of an external resource, or ask questions about which tests are being run in each order, etc. Combine this with an in-memory database (like [HSQL](http://hsqldb.org/)) and you won't even need to worry about having a running database somewhere to run against, making your build much more portable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I will create a new test class then. And I'm already running the tests in transactions using spring ;)

Answer (score 2):

JUnit will run all methods annotated with `@Before` and `@After` for each test so you will need to split your tests into two classes.

Answer (score 0):

Define your own BlockJUnit4ClassRunner:

```
public class WithoutBeforeAfter extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

    public WithoutBeforeAfter(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);
    }

    @Override
    protected Statement withBefores(FrameworkMethod method, Object target, Statement statement) {
        if(method.getName().equals("methodNameIgnore@Before")){
            return statement;
        }else{
            return super.withBefores(method, target, statement);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Statement withAfters(FrameworkMethod method, Object target, Statement statement) {
        if(method.getName().equals("methodNameIgnore@After")){
            return statement;
        }else{
            return super.withAfters(method, target, statement);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it in your test case:

```
@RunWith(value=WithoutBeforeAfter.class)
```

At least it is available in JUnit 4.8.